# Import Excel file using File Path Value from existing SQL table in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, dynamic, ssis

I am working in SSIS and would like to bring in Excel data that has a RetentionStatus = "Keep" only from an existing SQL table that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to import the data for the FileName where RetentionStatus = "Keep"? In the above table, that would give us the ability to dynamically import the dataset, dataset3.xls, into SSIS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use an Execute SQL task to read the file name that has "Keep" as the retention status, and store the result in a package variable.

Then create an Excel connection that the variable in place of the file name in the connection string expression.   Then use that connection as the source of a dataflow task to import the data.

Comment: Thanks @Tab Alleman, this was exactly the direction that I needed to figure it out! I am a noob with SSIS and am still getting familiar with the basic functions. Thanks again!